# Extract values from a list using a numpy range of indices between every two numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract a range of indices contained in the `'ranges'` list from the `'nums'` array.

For example:

```
ranges=np.arange(10, 100, 10).tolist() 
#[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

nums=np.arange(10, 1000, 5.5)
```

Here, I want to extract indices 10 to 20, and then 20 to 30 and so on until indices `80` to `90` specified in the `'ranges'` list from the `'nums'` array. I'm not sure how to cycle between every two numbers through the `'ranges'` list.

If I just had to extract 2-3 ranges of indices, I would just hard code the indices and slice-

```
idx1 = nums[10:21]
idx2 = nums[20:31]
idx3 = nums[30:41]
```

But this gets tedious to do for various combinations of ranges, especially in my original dataset with almost 100 ranges of indices to extract.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a loop

Comment: Looks like it is just reshaping what you aim to do: `nums[10:].reshape(-1,10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> ranges = [10, 20, 35, 42]
>>> for start, end in zip(ranges[:-1], ranges[1:]):
...     print(start, end)
...
10 20
20 35
35 42
```

(Of course, do your extraction in place of print)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop with a chosen step:

```
idxs = []

for n in range(10, 1000, 10):
    idx.append(nums[n:n+11])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
dic={}
for i in np.transpose([ranges[:-1],ranges[1:]]):
     dic[str(i[0])+"-"+str(i[1])]=nums[i[0]:i[1]]
print(dic)
```